# DataTextFormatString not working in DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Let's say I'm writing an ASP.NET app that uses a `DropDownList` to display a single column, which contains `DateTime` objects, from a programatically created `DataTable`. I would like to use a specific format of `DateTime`, so I added a `DataTextFormatString` parameter to my `DropDownList`.

Page.aspx (website):

```
[...]

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddList1" runat="server"
 DataTextField="MyDate" DataTextFormatString="{0:d}" />

[...]
```

Page.aspx.cs (script):

```
[...]

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("MyDate");

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["MyDate"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i);
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

ddList1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
ddList1.DataBind();

[...]
```

However, that format does not change at all. If I add dummy text outside of `{0:d}`, it does appear on my page, but the `DateTime` object just does not want to format how I want it to. After looking for a solution, literally everyone says that I need to set `DataTextFormatString` properly. But come on, am I not doing that? What am I missing here?

Huge note: I would like `DataTextFormatString` to stay declarative (in Page.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `DataTable`, not The `DataTextFormatString`.

You need to specify the DataType of the column in the DataTable, otherwise it will default to string and you cannot apply formatting.
So use

```
dt.Columns.Add("MyDate", typeof(DateTime));
```

And then the formatting in DataTextFormatString will work

```
DataTextFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}"
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that `DataTable` automatically converts stuff to string if you don't specify a type, but it indeed makes sense when you think about it.